# Git on Azure self hosted agent pipelines

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

I am building an Azure pipeline for a GitHub web site to run on Windows Self-Hosted agents.
The default branch for the GitHub project is develop, all developers commit to this branch.  I want a script that will merge develop to release for the time where a version is on tests and merge release to master once in production.

I'm new with git commands, I know the pipeline runs under a service account on the agent, behind a proxy and the pipeline impersonate somehow to another account to connect to GitHub.

To test my script, I logged onto the server as the service account and ran the following commands:

```
REM At start, the pipeline is on the develop branch so I move to release branch
C:\Agent\_work\29\s> git checkout release
>Updating files: 100% (928/928), done.
>Previous HEAD position was a62***: *comment*
>Switched to a new branch 'release'
>Branch 'release' set up to track remote branch 'release' from 'origin'.

C:\Agent\_work\29\s>git tag "branchTests"

C:\Agent\_work\29\s>git status
>On branch release
>Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release'.
>
>nothing to commit, working tree clean

REM I understood I had to first get the release branch and then pull the develop branch over it before pushing it all back
C:\Agent\_work\29\s>git pull origin develop
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

C:\Agent\_work\29\s>git push --verbose --repo=release --set-upstream release
>Pushing to release
>fatal: 'release' does not appear to be a git repository
>fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
>Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have two questions:

1. Is my script correct in that context ?
2. Can this username error come from that I use the service account ? I should impersonate somehow as the same account the pipeline does ?

Thanks.

########## Update 1

I noticed that I don't need to add this if I don't disable the checkout in the pipeline

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "xxx"
git remote set-url origin https://user:{GitHubPAT}@github.com/xxx/xxx.git
```

I have two files:

```
stages:
  - stage: InitRelease
    jobs:
    - job: Branch
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          clean: true
          persistCredentials: true
        - template: git-branch-source-2-target.yml@templates
          parameters:
            Tag: '${{ variables.projectName }}_${{ variables.buildId }}'
```

#### git-branch-source-2-target.yml

```
parameters:
- name: 'SourceBranch'
  default: 'develop'
  type: string

- name: 'TargetBranch'
  default: 'release'
  type: string

- name: 'Tag'
  default: ''
  type: string

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  enabled: true
  displayName: 'GIT Release'
  inputs:
      script: |
        git checkout ${{parameters.SourceBranch}}
        git pull origin 

        git checkout ${{parameters.TargetBranch}}
        git pull origin 

        git tag ${{parameters.Tag}}
        git push --tags

        git merge ${{parameters.SourceBranch}} 
        git push origin --all --verbose
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command in the cmd task of the pipeline:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "xxx"

git remote set-url origin https://user:{GitHubPAT}@github.com/xxx/xxx.git
git checkout develop
git pull origin
git checkout release
git merge develop
git push origin --all
```

[image]

Comment: That worked !
I added an extra "pull" though, thanks a lot !
I'll explain in Update 1